# Как отключить раскачивание в UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Имеется UIScrollView с контентом, как настроить UIScrollView, что бы при подъеме к верхней границе, он дальше не скролился (при этом после тача он возвращается на место (создавая эффект раскачивания)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключить полностью:

```
scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Отключить только для горизонтальной или вертикальной оси:

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо !!

Comment: @ВикторМишустин если ответ вам подошел, примите его нажатием галочки слева под рейтингом.